# Can you step back while debugging physical phone in xamarin or maui on VS 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, maui

This is a basic question that may help me to see what may be wrong with my setup.

I am fairly new to app development, so I am curious to know if others have been able to successfully step back/forward in code in xamarin or maui when debugging onto a physical device.

I am using Maui right now, but imagine it would be enabled if it was enabled with xamarin. I am trying to drag the debug statement forwards or backwards when I am breaked, and cannot. I am also trying on VS 2022.

Comment: As far as I know, Mono Debugger (SDB) does not support stepping backwards, it might depend on the specific platform as well whether this is supported. So probably no. You can read more here: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/soft-debugger/

Comment: This might be helpful ; [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022)